# Power of test and error Type I

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

I need some help with these multiple choice questions:

1) Considering a statistical test for the mean. **the error type I is a=0.027**. How at least is *the power of the test*? The possible answers are 0.027, 0.05, 0.10, 0, 1, 0.90

2) Considering a statistical test for the mean. **the error type II for a specific value is 0.10**. Then *the error type I* is less or equal than:

A. 0.027  B. 0.05  C. 0.10  D. 0.90   E. 0.50

Comment: Google "power curve in statistics". After understanding the power curve, you will get the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the power curve you can find that power increases as the $H_a$ is far from $H_o$. For example, given that $H_o: \mu = 0$, then the power will increase as $\mid \mu\mid$ increases. So the power will be reach the minimum when $H_o$ is true. In fact, power under $H_o$ is the probability of type 1 error, i.e., $\alpha$ level.

For the first question, 0.027 is the minimum of power of this test. For any other $H_a \ne H_0$, the power should $\ge$ 0.027.

For second question, if you can get the power = 0.10 at some $H_a \ne H_0$, the probability of type I error (power when $H_a = H_0$) should be less than 0.10.